# Problema para hacer merge

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-pull

Tenia un proyecto viejo que empece desde 0 nuevamente, la cuestión es que hice un push al repositorio remoto y se creo una nueva rama llamada master. Asi que me quedaron 2 ramas en el remoto main y master.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el problema es que no logro que aparezca en mi repositorio local la rama main ya hice un fetch.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probé varias cosas mas pero no logre que aparezca en mi repositorio local.

Gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Intenta haciendo un git pull, igual si te puede ayudar en algo GitHUb tiene un cliente de escritorio llamado [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/)

Comment: Si hago un pull me dice que ya esta actualizado el repositorio

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente pude arreglarlo.

A pesar de que en mi repositorio local no apareciera la rama main, al colocar el comando

- git checkout main

logre cambiar de rama de todas formas.
Luego hice el merge y elimine la rama master del repositorio remoto con

- git push origin :master

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

El comando `git branch` sin más argumentos solo muestra ramas *locales*. Si arrancaste un nuevo repositorio local usando la rama `master` en vez de `main` y empujaste a un repositorio donde ya había una rama `main`, para poder ver la rama *remota* tienes primero que hacer un `git fetch`, con eso lograrias ver la rama remota. Al hacer `git branch -a` (o con `-r`), te saldría listada la rama remota.... y finalmente si haces `git checkout main` se crearía la rama local `main` a partir de la remota.